# Using <a> + :after to make a better css ruby layout but alignment doesn't work

Tags: css, alignment

I've tried to reuse the ruby layout from the [learnJapanese reddit (example)](http://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/2vanzt/what_is_your_favorite_japanese_word/cofzx7r) which works with `<a href='#reading' title='hiragana'>japanese kanji</a>` and then does display the hiragana before the title via css for #reading :before.

In my case I want to display the reading below the word (using css :after) but I am not sure how I could align it with the rest of the text:

[image: unaligned text]

"onetwo continue" should be on the same line.

Here is an example of what I want this to look like:

[image]

jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/eex8gx6g/

Comment: You want continue to be on the same line as onetwo is on now? Or you want them both to be below the subs/sbus things.

Comment: Yes on the same line. I've tried to make it clearer by adding a screenshot of what I want it to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using position:relative for the subtitle and a margin-bottom to accommodate for the subsequent lines of text:

```
a[href$="/reading"], a[href$="#reading"] {
    ...
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    ...
}

...

a[href$="/reading"]:after, a[href$="#reading"]:after {
    ...
    position:absolute;
    top:1.4em;
    left:0em;
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eex8gx6g/5/

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread what you were trying to do.  Give me a minute.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eex8gx6g/2/  - This puts the subs underneath the original using absolutely positioned offsets on a relatively positioned parent.

Comment: I dunno.  If you know that the designated A's will always have this bottom content, then you can just give them a margin-bottom:

http://jsfiddle.net/eex8gx6g/4/

But generally, this is a flaw in trying to use the system in a general purpose context.

Comment: Yeah, the margin-bottom looks good to me and also works better than what I tried to do with line-height.  What I try to do is kind of a kludge anyway, as I try to resolve the issue that html-ruby just looks bad and there is no way to set a background color or font-size, so it's a workaround for now anyways.   Thanks!